# How to add a column which does a string addition of values from other column based on condition from another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

```
column1       column2
product1    action_of_interest1
product2    action_of_interest1
product3    random_action
product1    action_of_interest2
```

I want to add a `new_column` (an entry separated by comma) which adds/concatenates entries from column1 whenever column2 value is `action_of_interest1` and subtracts the running concatenated array whenever column2 value is `action_of_interest2. For random_actions, do nothing just print whatever is the current array.

This is the resulting table:

```
column 1          column2                         new_column
product1     action_of_interest1                   product1
product2     action_of_interest1                  product1,product2
product3     random_action                    product1,product2
product1     action_of_interest2                  product2
```

How to do this in BigQuery/SQL?

Comment: Is there a third column that can be used for ordering purposes?

Comment: yes, the rows are ordered by 3 more columns, which are not shown here. Ideally, it would be great if the order of the rows don't change.

Comment: you need a window function. `select *, string_agg(column1) over ( RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) from .... `   Please [see](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#compute_a_subtotal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using window functions:

```sql
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT "product1" AS column1, "action_of_interest1" AS column2, 1 AS column3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "product2" AS column1, "action_of_interest1" AS column2, 2 AS column3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "product3" AS column1, "random_action" AS column2, 3 AS column3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "product1" AS column1, "action_of_interest2" AS column2, 4 AS column3
),
running_agg as (
  SELECT
    *,
    ARRAY_AGG(IF(column2 = 'action_of_interest1', column1, '')) OVER (ORDER BY column3 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as action_of_interest1,
    ARRAY_AGG(IF(column2 = 'action_of_interest2', column1, '')) OVER (ORDER BY column3 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as action_of_interest2
  FROM sample
)
SELECT 
  * EXCEPT (action_of_interest1, action_of_interest2),
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(
    ARRAY(
      SELECT * FROM UNNEST(action_of_interest1) 
      EXCEPT DISTINCT 
      SELECT * FROM UNNEST(action_of_interest2)
    ), 
    ','
  ) AS new_column
FROM running_agg
```

Output:

```
column1     column2                 column3     new_column
product1    action_of_interest1     1           product1
product2    action_of_interest1     2           product1,product2
product3    random_action           3           product1,product2
product1    action_of_interest2     4           product2
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks.

It is failing on:
`WITH sample AS (
  SELECT "product1" AS column1, "action_of_interest1" AS column2, 1 AS column3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "product2" AS column1, "action_of_interest1" AS column2, 2 AS column3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "product3" AS column1, "random_action" AS column2, 3 AS column3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "product1" AS column1, "action_of_interest2" AS column2, 4 AS column3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "product1" AS column1, "action_of_interest1" AS column2, 4 AS column3
),`
As soon as I add an item, which was removed earlier, it does not add it back.

Comment: The final row of the solution should be `product1
action_of_interest1
4
product2, product1` instead of `product1
action_of_interest1
4
product2`

Comment: Imagining column3 is time column, is there a way to invoke except only if `action_of_interest2` took place after `action_of_interest1` for the same product? Thanks.